# Destroy subscriptions to an observable in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I'm hunting memory leaks in a large knockout application. I've found a pattern of memory leak that I can't seem to find any mention of elsewhere.

Consider the following code, using the debug version of knockout:

```
var myObservable = ko.observable();
console.log('Before any subscriptions: ' + Object.keys(myObservable._subscriptions).length);

var myObservableArray = ko.observableArray([]);

var myComputed = ko.computed(function() {
    myObservableArray().forEach(function(observableItem) {
        var test = observableItem();
    });
});

myObservableArray([myObservable]);

console.log('After adding to array: ' + Object.keys(myObservable._subscriptions).length);

myObservableArray([]);

console.log('Removed from array: ' + Object.keys(myObservable._subscriptions).length);
```

The console will output the following:

```
Before any subscriptions: 0
After adding to array: 1
Removed from array: 1
```

So, the issue is, in my app, there comes a point where I am done using a given observable (a property on a control view model, the control has now been removed). I've released all references to it, but the global computed retains a reference to it, thus keeping my control's viewmodel from being garbage collected.

I do not want to dispose of the computed - I still need that for other controls. I really need to destroy/dispose of the observable itself somehow.

What am I missing here?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/24359/

Comment: See, the problem here is it seems that "once a dependency of a computed, always a dependency of a computed" until the computed is finally disposed. This doesn't work when you have a higher level computed that needs to access lower-level observables that have shorter lifetimes. There must be a way to remove the specific observable's subscription from the computed?

Comment: If you do not want to dispose of `myComputed`, but no longer care about `myObservableArray`, then what does `myComputed` represent?  Basically, you would need the computed to not access `myObservableArray` when it is re-evaluated, but I am not sure in your app what value `myComputed` would represent?

Comment: A computed's dependencies are re-calculated each time that it is evaluated, so what it depends on is a result of the latest evaluation.

Comment: Thanks RP. I DO want to keep myObservableArray. And I DO want to keep myComputed. I've removed myObservable from the array, but it still appears to have a subscription from the observable. I would expect its subsription count to go back to 0 in this case.

Comment: Sorry I missed part of your question, will look at your fiddle

Comment: If you look at `myObservable._subscriptions` afterwards, there is not actually a subscription just the key representing the event name (`change`) with an empty array. So, it has nothing has a dependency to it.